# 301 redirects with express

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-301

I have a node.js website which will replace an existing site. Some of the URLs in the new site are different to those in the old so i need to set up 301 redirects for these.

currently i am using the following to re-route specific pages:

`app.get('contact-us',  (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect(301, 'http://www.example.com/contact');
});`

However is there a way to re-route based on patterns? for example on the old site i have /products/id/product-name which i need to re-route to /catalogue/id/product-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[express-redirect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-redirect)** module to get this done in an effective manner,

You can install this by issuing the below command,

```
npm install express-redirect
```

To initialize,

```
var express = require("express")
  , redirect = require("express-redirect");

var app = express();
redirect(app);
```

For redirecting,

```
// just a simple redirect 
app.redirect("/p/:id", "/page/:id");

// you want it permanent? 
app.redirect("/p/:id", "/page/:id", 301);

// if you want to append the query string (?foo=bar) 
app.redirect("/p/:id", "/page/:id", 301, true);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i have a bunch of pages that i want to redirect but there is no subfolder..
e.g. 
 app.redirect("/page1", "/pagepage1", 301);
 app.redirect("/page2", "/pagepage2", 301);

and maybe thousands... how do i do this